# Get data from multiple SharePoint servers in the network

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does SharePoint Management Shell (2010 or above) have the feature of getting data from multiple servers in the network? For example, in the network, I have 2 SP servers. Can I run Get-SPSite on one of the server (or another server which is not any of the SP server) to get all site collections of both SP servers?

I know Exchange Management Shell has this feature, does SP have it too? or will it have this feature in SP 2013?

Or, will have to remote to each server?

thanks

Comment: Your talking about "multiple servers". The important thing is whether they belong to the same farm. Are you talking about multiple SharePoint farms?

Comment: ideally, they could belong to different farms. but for now, we can assume they belong to the same farm. will the SP management shell support getting data for all servers in the same farm? or, we have to write a script? I see Exchange management shell has this feature, that's why I'm wondering.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one farm, all sites, web applications and webs in that farm are accessible with the Management Shell. If there are several farms you will have to use powershell remoting to access the other farms.